# Could I possibly have a tables hidden from the outset?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have had some success integrating this code snippet with my data tables.

The only problem is that there seems to be a flicker of all the tables on screen when the page is loading or refreshing, before even entering any search/filter/query words.

I have tried using hide/show with CSS and variations of displaying results in JavaScript and HTML, but with no ultimate fix. I would love to know how to resolve this problem and with keeping mark.js highlight in effect, With-in an exaple.

```js
var input, table, rows, markInstance;
window.onload = function init() {
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);
  clear();
}

function ContactsearchFX() {
  clear();
  if (input.value.length == 0) return;
  filterRows(input.value);
  highlightMatches(input.value);
}

function clear() {
  markInstance.unmark();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function filterRows(text) {
  var part = text.toUpperCase();
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      var content = td.innerText.toUpperCase();
      if (content.includes(part)) {
        row.style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}

function highlightMatches(text) {
  markInstance.mark(text);
}
```

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.hints {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

myInput:invalid~.hints {
  display: block;
}

mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.js"></script>

<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
    Search Titles: 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required 
           onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()"
           placeholder="Search Titles" />
    <span class="hints">
      Hints: type "POINT AT WHERE DATA TABLES ARE"...
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <TABLE>
        <tr>
          <td>POINT AT WHERE DATA TABLES ARE INSEED</td>
        </tr>
      </TABLE>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I wrapped your code into a runnable snippet, but there are no data loaded, so the problem can't be reproduced here..

Comment: in the CSS, `myInput` should be `#myInput` to match the id (or converted to a class and `.myInput`). similar for `mark` which does not exist in the HTML

Comment: I'm not seeing any flickering in your code example, and it's not really clear what you're asking.

Comment: You can simply give `body {opacity: 0}` and, at the end of your `onLoad` routine add a class to it which applies `opacity: 1`. You probably want to also give it `transition: opacity .3s ease-out;`. But do note that, if your script errors and never gets to adding that class, your entire page will remain transparent. It's not ideal but it's the go-to solution for fixing any FOUC issues.

Comment: @Aprillion and APAD1, I was able to see the flicker in the code sample that Aprillion created. You might need to click "Run Code Snippet" multiple times to chatch it because it only lasts a fraction of a second.

Comment: No flickering in this example, only when my data tables are in inserted as a nested table within the code. Mark.js working fine. Is this helping? Like if you press refresh a good few times it can be seen and even more so when data tables are inserted.

Comment: Hi and thanks @Andrei Gheorghiu. Could you actually fit your code into snippet for me - not sure I'm arranging the code properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think I see the issue that you were referring to and I believe I have a solution for you. I think the issue was occurring because it takes a split second for the JavaScript to execute and set the `<tr>` in your table to `display: none;`. So I changed your `<tr>` to be `<tr style="display:none;">` right from the start. Try it out in the sample below.

Keep clicking "run code" to simulate loading your page. I don't see a flash of text like I did in the included sample.

```js
/* */
var input, table, rows, markInstance;
window.onload = function init() {
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  table = document.getElementById('myTable');
  rows = table.querySelectorAll('tr');
  markInstance = new Mark(table);
  clear();
}

function ContactsearchFX() {
  clear();
  if (input.value.length == 0) return;
  filterRows(input.value);
  highlightMatches(input.value);
}

function clear() {
  markInstance.unmark();
  for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    rows[i].style.display = 'none';
  }
}

function filterRows(text) {
  var part = text.toUpperCase();
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i];
    var td = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      var content = td.innerText.toUpperCase();
      if (content.includes(part)) {
        row.style.display = "";
      }
    }
  }
}

function highlightMatches(text) {
  markInstance.mark(text);
}
//*/
```

```css
.input-wrap {
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

.hints {
  display: none;
  margin-top: 12px;
}

myInput:invalid~.hints {
  display: block;
}

mark {
  background: orange;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mark.js/8.11.1/mark.js"></script>
<div class="input-wrap">
  <label>
    Search Titles: 
    <input id="myInput" type="text" required 
           onkeyup="ContactsearchFX()"
           placeholder="Search Titles" />
    <span class="hints">
      Hints: type "POINT AT WHERE DATA TABLES ARE"...
    </span>
  </label>
</div>

<table id="myTable" style="width: 100%" class="style1">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <TABLE>
        <tr style="display: none">
          <td>POINT AT WHERE DATA TABLES ARE INSEED</td>
        </tr>
      </TABLE>
  </tr>
</table>
```